# Xcode iPhone project no longer debugs on my iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

My Xcode iPhone project no longer debugs on my iPhone.

When I run it from Xcode, it builds, downloads to iPhone, and then shows:  "GDB: Running..." for half a minute, and then Xcode shows:
"Error from Debugger: The program being debugged is not being run."

..and the iPhone shows springboard.

If I click the app's icon, the app runs ok.

Answer (score 2):

You're propably building with an ad hoc provisioning profile. Make sure you're building using your team development provisioning profile and that you allow debugging in your Entitlements.plist.